# Chevy Blazer 4.3 with p0303 error (cylinder 3 misfire) shortly after running medium-hot: now wonky idle, but smooth at high RPMs

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, misfire, fuel-injectors, gm

I've got a 97 Chevy Blazer with the 4.3 and 281k miles. It might be of-note that a shop replaced my Lower Intake Manifold gasket about 18 months ago.

At the very end of a long trip this weekend it started to overheat while idling. I shut it off shortly before the temp gauge read 210 (the red starts about 240/250). When it cooled somewhat I discovered it was low on coolant ..even though plenty was in the overflow reservoir. So I topped it off and replaced the old radiator cap, which I think was the source of a slow leak. But when I started it back up, no more than 30 minutes later) I had a new engine code, p0303, which is "Cylinder 3 Misfire Detected". Also, it seemed to have a rough, unusual, pulsing rhythm at idle, not exaggerated, but I thought I noticed something different about the idle.

It was late, so I cleared the engine codes and let it sit over night. Now today on my way to work, it started up great just like usual, and I didn't notice anything weird at first--however it was probably getting extra fuel then due to being cold. But once it warmed up, I thought the idle seemed rough and heavy, kinda shaking the cab, and definitely different from normal. My drive to work is only about 10 miles/20 minutes, and it hasn't kicked a new engine code, but I'm expecting one any moment with it idling like this.

Looking into symptoms/solutions, I found [this thread](https://blazerforum.com/forum/2nd-gen-s-series-1995-2005-tech-41/p0303-70801/) where similar symptoms were fixed by addressing JUST the #3 cylinder fuel injector. Also, [right here on mechanics.se](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/18264/4509), a different user emphasizes the potential for the SCPI (fuel injection) system to influence misfiring. Meanwhile, over on YouTube, a different guy fixed his misfire by just [replacing the distributor cap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOmu_PXEeA0). And closer to the worse-case scenario, someone suggested the [potential for bent valves](https://blazerforum.com/forum/2nd-gen-s-series-1995-2005-tech-41/help-ran-hot-now-misfire-rough-idle-59309/) on an unresolved thread over at BlazerForum.

Tonight, if I can get to it, I'm going to check the #3 spark plug for fouling evidence as well as the condition of its plug wire for wear/melting/shorting. But I don't suspect the electrical components because wouldn't the problem be more aggressive, regular, and obvious with near immediate error codes?

I suppose my question is: **How can I rule out an issue with bent valves following overheating?** And would bent valves feel smooth again at high RPMs (basically anything above idle?)

Secondary question related to the scenario: **Is it realistic that a mild overheating might finish off the old OEM fuel injector spider, or an individual cylinder injector poppet?** What is the best way to rule it out?

I'm optimistic that rough idle but smooth running at RPMs above idle suggests a fuel delivery fuel mixture issue to the problem cylinder, rather than bent valves. So someone with a strong opinion on that would carry a lot of weight.